# ReadOnly Option on ruby and rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails project and I don't know why it seems that a Model is set to ReadOnly but I din't do anything and i don't want this, so....
How I can delete this option on my db or on my model?

Comment: Are you calling `record.readonly!` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to make all the files in the current directory have all permissions type.

I am using Linux

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it insert into the model

```
def readonly?
false
end
```